# Putting dropdown menu in bootstrap Carousel creates visibility issue

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used bootstrap carousel for slide show, I am putting bootstrap `button-group` as `dropdown` in my slideshow, when i click on dropdown(created using buttons). Dropdown after slideshow is not shown.

[image]

as displayed in image majors after marketing are not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Carousel .carousel-inner class has an overflow:hidden

If you take that out the menu will display....but of course it will affect all the other items you have in your other slides...especially images, so I would suggest that you make sure that the height/width etc...of all these are equal and see if that will work ok at different media sizes etc....